# Having issues controlling a servo from pi-blaster

Tags: servo

I'm trying to learn more about making electronics making stuff.  Right now I'm just trying to get a servo to move so I can go on to bigger things.

I have a Pi B+ running Rasbian and an HS-311 servo connected to a battery pack with 4 AA's in it.  I've installed pi-blaster and as far as I can tell it is running but I can't get any movement out of the servo.  Here is a diagram of my wiring. [image]

As you can see I've added an LED onto the control wire for the servo to see if anything is happening.  If I run `echo "17=1" > /dev/pi-blaster` the led lights up but the servo doesn't move.  Running `echo "17=0.5" > /dev/pi-blaster`dims the led and `echo "17=0" > /dev/pi-blaster` will turn it off but nothing I do will get the servo to turn.

I'm not sure at this point if I've wired something wrong or if I'm doing something wrong in code.

Update:  Thanks to @joan I had forgot to ground the control circuit with the Pi. I did so and replaced the batteries as they were to weak to control the servo.
The servo will now go to a few positions;

- `echo "17=.04" > /dev/pi-blaster` gives position of 0
- `echo "17=.24" > /dev/pi-blaster` gives position of 190

Values >0.04 <0.24 move the servo in equal increments.
Values <0.04 >0 and >0.24 <1 move the servo to 0 and 190 respectively
A value of 1 or 0 turns the servo off without moving it.
I'm not sure if missing something as I had thought that 0 would move the servo full stop one way and 1 would move it full stop the other way.  Is there some defaults I should be setting?

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect the grounds.

In this case there is no connection between the Pi ground and the battery and servo grounds.

Connect a wire between the battery ground (or servo ground, which is the same thing) and a Pi ground pin.

This gives a circuit to allow the control signal to flow.

Comment: Doh, although that makes total sense it didn't make any difference.  The LED still lights and the servo doesn't move.

Comment: Oops I needed to update the batteries I was using.